# extracting gt_table from gt_group not giving proper results

Tags: r, gt

I am trying to store a bunch of t-tables in a gt group for quick display.  say I have a list of accounts like:

```
accounts <- c(
    "Cash",
    "Accounts Receivable(A/R)",
    "Interest Receivable",
    "AFDA",
    "Inventory",
    "Supplies On Hand (SOH)")
```

I then write a for loop to make a table for every account:
`

```
TaccGt <- gt_group()
for (i in accounts) {
  GTtemp <- gt(data.frame(t(l1))) %>% 
    tab_header(i)%>% 
    cols_width(everything()~px(75)) %>% 
    tab_options(column_labels.hidden = TRUE,
                table.border.top.style = "hidden",
                table.border.bottom.style = "hidden",
                data_row.padding = px(100)
    ) %>% 
    tab_style(
      style = cell_borders(
        sides = c("right","top"),
        color = "black",
        weight = px(2),
      ),
      locations=cells_body()
    )%>% 
    tab_style(
      style = cell_borders(
        sides = c("right"),
        color = "white",
        weight = px(2),
      ),
      locations=cells_body(2,1)
    )
  TaccGt[i] <- grp_add(GTtemp)
}
```

When I run the code in the loop I get exactly what I want, a nice little t-table that I will then print with the as_latex() function to add to a pdf.  But when I put them into the group I have it stripped down to a tibble that doesn't have any of the features from the above code.

What gives??  I haven't found many people giving examples of gt_group in a loop.

Thanks!